# Hibernate Search facet returns values in lowercase

Tags: java, lucene, hibernate-search

I'm a newbie to Hibernate Search facets. I'm using facets and I notice you can only return the `value` of the `fieldName`

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.2/api/

The problem I'm having has to do with my standard analyzer indexing my values in lowercase. So far everything is good until I need to display the data.

How do I return the value from the facet in it's original case, example `Ford`, `Chevrolet` etc rather than `ford`, `chevrolet`?

Is there an efficient way to get the value from the database by returning the pk from the value and build an actual object from the database? Or is it recommended to store the value in the index in it's original format and do a getFacetQuery to get it? I don't know anything about the *getFacetQuery*, so this might not be possible.

example

```
@Entity
public class Make {

@Field(store = Store.no)
private String name

}
```

values

```
database: Chevy|Ford
index: chevy|ford
```

facet

```
public FacetingRequest getMakeFacetRequest(QueryBuilder builder) {
    return builder.facet()
        .name("make")
        .onField("make.name")
        .discrete()
        .orderedBy(FacetSortOrder.FIELD_VALUE)
        .includeZeroCounts(false)
        .maxFacetCount(10)
        .createFacetingRequest();
 }
```

Results

```
chevy|ford
```

However I'd like the original case from the database.

Please recommend a best practice. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the solution to my issue was to provide another field to my index that was not analyzed. Example

Entity

```
private class Make {
@Fields({
        @Field(name = "name", analyzer = @Analyzer(definition = "searchtokenanalyzer")),
        @Field(name = "label", analyze = Analyze.NO)
    })
    private String name;
}
```

Facet Query

```
@Override
    public FacetingRequest getMakeFacetRequest(QueryBuilder builder) {
        FacetingRequest facetingRequest = builder.facet()
                .name("make")
                .onField("make.label")
                .discrete()
                .orderedBy(FacetSortOrder.FIELD_VALUE)
                .includeZeroCounts(true)
                .maxFacetCount(10)
                .createFacetingRequest();
        return facetingRequest;
    }
```